# Email Signature Pictures not Coming Through Merge Field

Tags: email, lightning-templates

As I create an email template for a user, the images set up in their email signature are not coming through via merge field. When they come through on an email they are showing as the standard HTML text. The workaround is to add each email signature image to the template and remove them from the actual signature, which results in issues for any one-off email someone wants to send.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.